# Set Theory Cartesian Product Subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is probably really trivial but it's confused me a bit, If i've got the cartesian product of 2 sets how do I express the relation which is a subset of the two sets?

```
For example: A X B .. A = {1, 2, 3, 4} and B = {blue, red, orange, green}
```

How do I provide an answer to the question: note the relation which is a subset of A X B, that relates numbers to colours?

(I'm pretty new at this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relation here would not be a subset of the two sets, but rather, a subset of $A\times B$.

$$A\times B = \{(x, y)\mid x \in A, y \in B\}$$

So you have a set of ordered pairs where the left component $x$ is a number in $A$, and the right component $y$ is a color in $B$.

For a relation that is a proper subset of $A\times B$, you'd need to define such a relation, whereby only some numbers are related to some colors. But every relation $R \subseteq A\times B$.

Comment: So I could say {(1, blue), (2, red), (3, orange), (4, green)} ?

Comment: Yes, you could. That is not $A \times B$, but it would be a relation. (it would also be a bijective function!)

Comment: Okie thanks! that makes sense

Comment: You're welcome, Crizly!